# Visual Studio is not stopping even after closing the app in debug mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am developing a windows form in c#. It is working fine but when I am running it in debug mode, I can see that visual studio is not stopping even after closing the form.

Below are some screenshots-

[image]

and

[image]

Probably my app is not releasing any resource. How can I deal with this problem? How to know which resource is still in use?

Comment: May be this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137394/debug-not-stopping-after-form-closing-in-visual-studio

Comment: Use `Break All` (the "pause" button) and look at the stacktrace/threads window to see where your application hangs.

Comment: What is your Application Exit mode? Is it set to explicit?

Comment: @DominicKexel: Your information was really helpful. Finally I figured it out the culprit thread. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have seen this issue in the past it was because my application hasn't actually exited. This would most likely be because you or a dependency still has a thread running that hasn't stopped. You can tell if this is the case by looking at the task manager and checking for `yourapplication.exe` or `yourapplication.vshost.exe`. If either of these is open in the task manager you can kill it.

To fix this issue, make sure you call `Abort()` on all threads!

Comment: Bear in mind that you aren't resolving the problem, you are most likely hiding it. Run the application outside Visual Studio and check if the process is terminated after you close its form.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if you are using [ApplicationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of a form as the default message queue. If so, consider handling the form closing event of your form.

Comment: great point. It was actually the second View which wasn't closing.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try looking at the Processes from Start Task Manager. That could give you some information if a third party process initiated by the application is still running.